# Prevenir que explorador use cache con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cache

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me verifica por medio de ajax a un archivo llamado ultima_cuenta.php que hace una consulta y me devuelve el ultimo id de una tabla llamada cuentas, este codigo lo ejecuto una vez se abre la pagina y funciona perfectamente, el problema es que si lo necesito nuevamente, siempre me trae la misma cuenta a pesar de que ya no es la ultima, he leido que es por temas de cache, busco por varias partes e intenté ponerle el parametro   ajax.cache=false; pero no funciona

para que funcione debo refrescar el explorador con shift + F5 en el caso de chromem alguna idea para prevenir eso? debo estar haciendo algo mal en el parametro que puse

muchas gracias!!

tengo el function

```
function ultima_cuenta(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var respuesta=this.responseText;
      var respuesta_entero = parseInt(respuesta);
      $('#label_ultima_cuenta').text(respuesta_entero+1);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "../PHP/ultima_cuenta.php", true);
  ajax.cache=false; // intenté esto
  xhttp.send();
}
```

> ultima_cuenta.php

```
<?php

require 'conectar.php';

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cuentas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1" or die('Error. '.mysql_error());

$resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $fila["id"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia de `GET` a `POST`.

- Las peticiones `GET` **siempre** pasan por la cache. Se supone que, si pides un recurso, éste siempre será el mismo, y no es necesario *ir a buscarlo* al servidor.
- Las peticiones `POST` **nunca** pasan por la cache. Estas pidiendo al servidor que realice una acción, y el resultado no tiene porqué ser el mismo en sucesivas invocaciones.

  ```
  xhttp.open( "POST", "../PHP/ultima_cuenta.php", true );
  ```

Comment: Buenísimo el tip, Trauma, lo tendré presente en mis próximos desarrollos :) (yo siempre envío por POST, pero con esto, me aclara mucho más las opciones). Gracias por mi parte ;)